# Access YouTube or Vimeo API in iframe

Tags: api, iframe, youtube-api, vimeo-api, youtube-iframe-api

How can I access to youtube or vimeo api provided object from iframe's javascript ? Either window.parent does not work or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used the YouTube "iframe API", so I cannot comment on the Vimeo flow.

The below snippet is taken mostly verbatim from the api docs, except for the promise part. When the API is loaded, it will call a `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function that can do whatever is needed, in this case resolve a promise so we're sure everything is loaded.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'),
    firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function apiLoaded() {
  var apiPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
      resolve();
    };
  });

  return apiPromise; 
}
```

Be sure to always use the promise returned by `apiLoaded()` when trying to execute API calls, for example:

```
apiLoaded().then(function() {
  var player = new window.YT.Player('iVideoFrame', {
    events: {
      ...
    }
  });
});
```

This assumes that somewhere in your HTML you've defined an iframe (note the query params in the video URL):

```
<iframe id="iVideoFrame" type="text/html" width="..." height="..." frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoId?enablejsapi=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=1"></iframe>
```